# Does Software Update on 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, updates, keepassx

Does Ubuntu update software packages like KeePassXC in LTS versions or does LTS mean I keep the version that was current when the LTS was released?

I installed KeePassXC on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I don't recall now what version of KeePassXC it was when I first installed it, but as of today it's 2.3.1. The most up-to-date version is now 2.4.1. I understand I can get updates by Snap and PPA, but I'm curious if a normal Ubuntu software update will eventually update KeePassXC or whether it remains static throughout the LTS period.

Edited to add: I understand now from the responses that the software packages were frozen to the time of release and that normally they will remain static and not be updated with the normal "Check for software updates." Does this static approach hold true for "apt-get"-type approaches, or can I get updates that way, eventually? I note from the source code link that KeePassXC 2.3.1 is still the source, but don't understand if I can "force" an update outside of Snap or PPA.

Further edited as possible duplicate: The basic question was essentially a duplicate, but my first edit took it further - "as the repositories change, can I then "apt-get" an updated version. It appears the answer is "no, not safely."

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software

Comment: Trying to add wrong-version deb packages is an easy way to break your system. Ubuntu is designed such that you newer debs require release-upgrading the entire system to a newer release of Ubuntu. Snaps are designed differently - any snap will run on any version of Ubuntu. There are advantages and disadvantages to both approaches.

Comment: "*the software **packages** were frozen to the time of release*". This is incorrect.  The software **versions** were frozen to the time of release, and only **security updates** are released after that.  Exceptions are flash player, and web browsers like FF and Chromium.  (There might be a few others, but I can't think of them off the top of my head.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Ubuntu does not always provide the latest version of a software. And the latest version of the software provided depends on the Ubuntu version you are using. This is for stability of each specific Ubuntu version. One exception may be the web browser (e.g. *Firefox*) since it is critical from security point of view.

In your case you can look at the following:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=keepassxc

A more detailed explanation was given in a [similar Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software).

Answer (score 0):

The [KeePassXC download page](https://keepassxc.org/download/) provides a PPA:

```
https://launchpad.net/~phoerious/+archive/ubuntu/keepassxc
```

You can find a lot of information about "[What are PPAs and How do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)", but PPAs allows for someone other than Ubuntu to maintain and publish a package, and for your system to take in these updates when they are available.

This means that the software you're asking about, KeePassXC, is maintained by KeePassXC, not Ubuntu, and you'll have to ask them or look at their history and policies to determine their release schedule and planning.

When you upgrade Ubuntu, say from 16.04 to 18.04, all of these PPAs are disabled, and you will need to re-enable them.  Until you re-enable them, they will not and cannot update.  Most times you can just re-enable them.  Sometimes you need to follow new setup instructions.

To best answer your question, you should check out the [KeePassXC download page](https://keepassxc.org/download/) and see what they are claiming to be the latest version (which it seems you have) and compare that to the results of `apt search keepassxc`.  You can check the [KeePassXC PPA](https://launchpad.net/~phoerious/+archive/ubuntu/keepassxc) and confirm your `apt` has the latest available version by comparing the results to the PPA page.

*At this time*, the PPA page matches the KeePassXC download page latest version:

```
keepassxc   2.4.1-1ppa1~bionic1
```

If you do not see this version, you have outdated packages (`apt update`), no longer have this PPA enabled, or some other issue.  It seems that the latest version of KeePassXC is available in the PPA at this time.

Comment: Thank you, I actually did add a PPA yesterday, the one promoted by the KeePassXC team, and it did provide me the current 2.4.1 version of KeePassXC. I then discovered that I'd be dependent upon that person for updates, so and removed KPXC and purged the ppa. I didn't want a ppa if Ubuntu would eventually provide an update, however late. It appears I can't count on that, however.

Comment: You make very valid points, though KeePassXC (you've decide to trust) lists this PPA as the official PPA.  Since you're trusting KeePassXC, you should trust their website which lists the official PPA, but staying on Ubuntu's packages is very valid in many other scenarios.  KeePassXC wasn't in the official repos last time I checked so that is confusing, but until their website says otherwise, I'd use the official PPA.